# Distribute Spark processing independently over files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I have measurements over 10 years coming from 10 000 sensors.
This is available as ASCII files stored in HDFS (to be improved, not the topic of this request):

- one file per sensor
- one line per sample
- two columns (time, value)
- a one line header

As a proof of concept, I compute the mean for a sensor using Spark with the following SCALA code targeting **Spark v1.6.1**

```
// Read file as text
val lines = sc.textFile("/data/sensor_1.dat")
// Drop header
val header = lines.first
val lines_clean = lines.filter(line => line != header)
// Compute mean
val values = lines_clean.map(_.split("\t").last.toDouble)
val mean = values.sum / values.count
```

Now, I want to apply it over 10 000 files, getting one mean value for each of my sensors. How should I proceed ? Should I implement a loop ? Can I handle a RDD at file level, and not file line level ? Any better ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you have to use a loop to read each file, why would you use Spark? You're just doing some serial processing at that point. Is the problem that you dont have an ID for the sensor each reading applies to in each file?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the wholeTextFiles() method ([here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles(java.lang.String,%20int))), it reads a whole directory and returns a pair RDD with (filename, content) pairs.

The filename would then be the sensor and the content can be processed in a similar way to before.

Answer (score 0):

Data is stored in `hdfs` it means that it is distributed over your cluster and spark can achieve data parallelism but you write code as it was one directory, well you need to worry about partitions. Also transform data into parquet for that very reason if possible.

I strongly recommend to use `datasets` as `spark` will be able to optimise the computation.

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

```
case class Sensor(time: java.sql.Timestamp, value: Double)

val ds = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .csv(s"hdfs://${master}:9000/data.tsv")
.as[Sensor] 
 // tune by partition number   .partition(100)

val mean = ds.select(avg(col("value")).as("mean"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running Spark v1.6.1, not providing csv method. Any workaround would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the whole folder like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

val inputPath: String = "/data/"

val lines = sqlContext.read.text(inputPath)
  .select(input_file_name.alias("filename"), $"value")
  .rdd
```

Then you can process the `String` for the file name and the value the same way as you did in the question:

```
val linesClean = lines.filter(l => l.getString(1) != header).map(l => (l.getString(0), l.getString(1)))
val meanForEachFile = linesClean.groupByKey().map{
    case (name, linesInFile) => 
    val values = linesInFile.map(v => v.split("\t").last.toDouble)
    val mean = values.sum / values.count
    mean
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, execution returns me error: type mismatch, expecting an Int instead of "value" when at l.getString("value"). In case, I am using Spark v1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

As the data in  each file does not seem to include the sensor id you'd probably want to use the [wholeTextFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#wholeTextFiles(java.lang.String,%20int)) option which will load 
 each file into an pairRDD where the key is the file name. It will mean more parsing as you'd need to  parse the to get the sensor name and split the whole file from the value to get the samples - but at least you'd be able to distinguish which data belongs to which sensor.

You should note that the path you pass to wholeTextFiles (or textFile for that matter) can be a list of path including wildcard as in `sc.wholeTextFiles("/dir/to/first/sensor,/dir/to/second/sensor,/sensor[0-10]*,/etc")`

Comment: Thx. As a begineer, missing illustrating source code makes your answer difficult to test. Getting a RDD(String, String) from wholeTextFiles blocks me as my code handles RDD(String).

Comment: You can flatmap the RDD and split the second string to key,value tuples. then you can map over the RDD(String, (String,Double)) to transform it to Tuple3 (you probably want to manipulate the first string to get the sensor name from the filename. In the next step you can transform this to a dataframe and work with a higher level API (like spark SQL or the DF DSL) to get aggregates and whatnot per sensor